# What's the error here?

Tags: java, android

```
int i = 10000;
Integer.toBinaryString(i);
```

How can I make the `Integer.toBinaryString` method return leading zeroes as well? For example, for `i = 1000`, I want `00000000000000000000001111101000` to appear, not `1111101000`.

Comment: And yes, i did read there's other ways by doing it, but i dont want to copy n paste as i thought this would do the job

Comment: From the documentation: `This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2) with no extra leading 0s.` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29

Comment: But whats up with the wierd result? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The result is not weird it's binary (you know, one's and zero's). If you look at a Decimal to Binary Converter you will see that it is correct just without the leading zero's http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-binary-converter. If you just want the int in a String representation of it's int value, use `Integer.toString()`

Comment: Okay sorry it's because i was talking about 8 bits only, sorry, and thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to left pad the result with zeros, you could do:

```
String raw = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
String padded = "0000000000000000".substring(raw.length()) + raw;
```

Here I chose a width of 16 digits, you can adjust the width by the number of zeros in the string.

Note, if it is possible that `i > 2^16 - 1` then this will fail and you'll need to protect against that (32 zeros would be one approach).

### EDIT

Here's a more complicated version which formats to the smallest of 8, 16, 24, or 32 bits which will contain the result:

```
public class pad {
    public static String pbi ( int i ) {
        String raw = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        int n = raw.length();
        String zeros;
        switch ((n-1)/8) {
            case 0: zeros = "00000000";                         break;
            case 1: zeros = "0000000000000000";                 break;
            case 2: zeros = "000000000000000000000000";         break;
            case 3: zeros = "00000000000000000000000000000000"; break;
            default: return raw;
        }
        return zeros.substring(n) + raw;
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer : ");
        int i = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println( pbi( i ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this throw a error if its over 16 digits??

Comment: Yup, if that's a possibility, you'll need to deal with it somehow.